# Does the XMPP receipy still work in Franz

Tags: xmpp

I tried to use xmpp in Franz (https://meetfranz.com/) using the following github repo:
https://github.com/alexander-schranz/franz-xmpp-client

Following the instructions the Service can not be loaded/shown in the Franz client.

Renamed the folder and removed the "master". Not even the Dev-Tools provided by Franz are opening.
Am I doing something wrong, or is the repo depricated? It still talks about Franz 5.x (actual version 5.10), but the last change in the repo is 6 years ago.
Unfortunately I cannot find any other description to do so  :/

Comment: (1) Please explain your issue/problem with code and error logs.
(2) Is it same issue -> https://github.com/alexander-schranz/franz-xmpp-client/issues/9